# Email all the test results once nunit finishes the tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, email, nunit

I wrote unit tests using NUnit. Once all the tests are done, I want to email the Test results to all my team. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you using any form of CI? Many of the frameworks have a plugin that allows the propagation of the results via plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TFS, you can make use of [NUnit for Team Build](http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/) which would make your NUnit test results visible in the build log and incorporated into the data warehouse for reporting.

There is also [NUnitForVS](http://nunitforvs.codeplex.com/) which can publish results within TFS.

Going one of the above routes will allow you to leverage the current CI environment and is a much better approach to emailing the results as they surface.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is done using an automated build tool like Cruise Control.  It checks your code out of version control, builds the app, runs all the tests, packages the app, and sends it to the first deployment server.  Team members can view the complete results of the build and test cycle using a browser to check the build server dashboard.

I'd prefer that to getting e-mailed test results.  E-mail would soon become an annoyance.